# Triggering a build from another build(conditional) in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, build, build-process, build-automation, tfs-2015

I have created two build definition for two different builds in TFS 2015.

> Ex - Build1 and Build2

Both the are getting executed without an error.
What I want to perform is, I want to provide an argument in build one

> ex=Build2=True or False.

If the argument Build2=True after build definition Build1 successfully executed the build definition Build2 should get triggered.

And if Build2=False the build process should finish after execution of Build1.

I am able to do this in Jenkins by adding the Build2 to pipeline in postbuild tasks, since I am new in TFS 2015 so can anybody help me to accomplish this in TFS 2015

Comment: Chained builds are still not supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270617/how-to-chain-builds-in-tfs-2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Yan Sklyarenko mentioned, this feature is not supported right now, please vote the User Voice at website below:

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2165043-provide-build-configuration-dependencies-in-tfs-bu

Answer (score 3):

I created a Build Task that should allow to support your described scenario. It uses the TFS REST API to queue new builds and supports conditions, for example a check if the last build of a specified build definition was successful or not.

You can download it from the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks)

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to create Task Group for each build.

[you can read about Task Groups here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/library/task-groups)

and create one build that use some task group in his steps.