# How to trigger Process from process in TFS2015 Build

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, build, tfs-2015, vnext

I have lot of build's definitions using tasks (TFS 2015 vNext),
Some of them need to run from middle of running process
how can i perform that case

Thanks

Comment: Did you just mean a build trigger another build?

Comment: yes, i checked in the market place and found Release Trigger but not sure it does what i need

Comment: No, release trigger can't achieve what you want.

Comment: yes i get it, after i download it :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems what your described is very likely **chain the build definition**. This Feature is under plan, but don't have yet.

Check the QA on [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#can-i-chain-builds-so-that-one-build-triggers-another-):

> **Can I chain builds so that one build triggers another?**
>
> Not yet.

There's also an ancient suggestion on  [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2165043-provide-build-configuration-dependencies-in-tfs-bu) under planned , you could track the status.

Also take a look at this similar question: [How to chain builds in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270617/how-to-chain-builds-in-tfs-2015)