# Using personal library .jar in TFS Online build

Tags: java, git, maven, tfs

I'm trying to start doing continuous integration on my Java/Maven project, using Team Foundation Server.  I am trying to build two projects: a library, and a main project.

When I compile the main project from my local box, it's currently getting the library.jar file from a local Artifactory server (which my superiors would like to go away).

I've gotten the library to build, being triggered by changes to the git repo.  I would like the main project to be able to use this generated artifact when it compiles, but I cannot find documentation on how to point Maven to the TFS artifact.

Have you managed to do this in your own project?  How would I go about creating the reference to the library.jar?

**EDIT:**  I'm not necessarily looking to have build triggering.  I'm trying to figure out dependency management.

Comment: Can the build agent access to the artifactory server? If yes, you can publish the built library.jar file to the artifactory server.

Comment: I'm not using a local build server.  How do I get the TFSOnline build agent to see/get access to the Artifactory?  How do I tell TFSO where the Artifactory server is?

In my local build, I have all that info in Maven's settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I totally got your point, seems that you want to start doing continuous integration on this process: Your library project auto build triggered by changes to the git repo, then your main project build using the generated library.jar earlier.

It's likely **chain the build definition**. This Feature is under plan, but don't have yet.

Check the QA on [this website](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/define/triggers#can-i-chain-builds-so-that-one-build-triggers-another-):

> **Can I chain builds so that one build triggers another?**
>
> Not yet.

There's also an ancient suggestion on  [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2165043-provide-build-configuration-dependencies-in-tfs-bu) under planned , you could track the status.

Also take a look at this similar question: [How to chain builds in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270617/how-to-chain-builds-in-tfs-2015)

If you just want to build your Java app with Maven, look at this [tutorial](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/get-started/java-maven).

Comment: I'm currently building both projects manually from the Windows command line with Maven.  I've also managed to compile the library with TFS.  I don't know how to tell TFS about the dependency on that successfully compiled code.  Local Maven knows to look to Artifactory because of a global Maven file on my local machine.

Comment: I'm happy to wait for chaining builds.  I just want it to build.

Comment: There is a built-in build task call maven(maven) in tfs build definition, could this be helpful. Another way could nuget be helpful in this case, create your custom nuget package including the library files and add a nuget restore in the build definition. Then TFS  build agent will auto find the files and dependency.

Comment: The maven build step allows me to choose a pom.xml file, but doesn't have anywhere to set the global options (like in my local settings.xml file) to point it to the library location (whether in Artifactory or elsewhere).

Nuget's FAQ says that "The most recent version of NuGet supports C#, Visual Basic, F#, WiX, and C++." (not Java)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Powershell task in your build definition to download the library build artifacts via Rest API: [Get Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-artifacts).

For the settings.xml file, you can upload it into the version control and specify "--settings settings.xml" to use it.