# Using TFS Artifacts as a Maven Dependency

Tags: java, maven, tfs, artifacts

I have 2 Maven projects , a library and an App , 
Both are built and stored as an Artifacts in TFS (2017)

I would like to import project A directly from the TFS Artifacts into Project B 
But apparently the structure the TFS artifacts are kept and the fact they do not keep the POM.XML prevents the Project B maven file to indentify the TFS Artifactory as a Maven artifactory and import the Library .

My question is . 
1) Is it even possible to use TFS Artifacts the same way Maven artifacts are used ? 
2) How does it done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Start using a repository manager like Nexus, Artifactory or Archiva and deploy those artifacts there...using TFS/SVN/Git as an artifact repository is simply the wrong way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure Project A is deployed correctly to your **Maven repository** (instead or in addition to the deployment to TFS - I would have kept in TFS only the sources...). Then it would be very simple for maven to find project A and add it to B as a dependency.

Hope that helps.

Comment: But i dont wish it to be deployed to the Global Maven repository , I want it to be stored locally on my TFS server ... also is the TFS repository and Maven repository are two different things?

Comment: i didnt mean Global maven repo... i meant your local maven repo. do u have in your organization maven repo like nexus or artifactory? even if not, deploy it to your local (.m2)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to publish the Artifacts of Project A to a shared folder (Artifact Type: `File Share`), then reference it directly or add a copy task to copy the artifacts to Project B.

Besides, it sounds like the chain builds in TFS. You can try the extension: [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks), the task that can be used to trigger a new Build so that build-chaining is possible. Supports as well conditional triggers. See below similar thread for details:

- [How to chain builds in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270617/how-to-chain-builds-in-tfs-2015)
- [Using personal library .jar in TFS Online build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147907/using-personal-library-jar-in-tfs-online-build)

---

Another workaround is upgrading to TFS 2018 or migrating to VSTS to install a Maven artifact is as a dependency of another artifact with the Maven CLI.

Please see [Install Maven artifacts using VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/maven/install) for details.

Related documents:

- [Set up the Maven client in VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/maven/pom-and-settings)
- [Publish Maven artifacts using VSTS and TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/maven/publish)
- [Build your Java app with Maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/apps/java/build-maven?tabs=vsts)