# background process launched by TFS is killed when switching to next step

Tags: batch-file, tfs

I have some trouble keeping alive a background process when launched by TFS.
Usually I use a batch that launch a java server (new window), as long as I keep this window open it works properly.

```
C:\Users\TFSService\mbs-iot-sdk\osgi\bin\vms\jdk\server.bat
```

In order to make my process automatic, I include this in TFS. In the step I call a batch that contains the following:

```
cd C:\Users\TFSService\mbs-iot-sdk\osgi\bin\vms\jdk // necessary to find the batch
start C:\Users\TFSService\mbs-iot-sdk\osgi\bin\vms\jdk\server.bat
```

In my task manager, I can see in background tasks that java is launched (no new window is opened), exactly as it behaves when launching directly the batch. But after a few seconds, when TFS switches to the next step, it stops. 
Then the next step carries on but fails as it requires the server to be launched.
Is there a particular way of doing it in TFS ?

thank you

Alexandre

Comment: Are you doing your build on your local machine or on a Build Agent? If you are doing this on a Build Agent it is most likely using a folder name such as Drive:\Builds\n (where n is typically 1-4). Your configuration could be different. Add some logging to your bat file to figure out what is happening.

Comment: I'm using a build agent. The following command is executed in  (workingFolder = c:\Build\_work\5\s).

Comment: I am not convinced that you need the CD command. Is that messing up subsequent commands in the bat file? Add some logging to a temp file in your bat file to figure out what is happening.

Comment: The CD command is necessary, otherwhise the .bat file "is not seen as an internal command, or external, exec, etc.". I have TFS log traces but they don't provide relevant information. I tried to order tasks differently so the two consecutive tasks have the same working folder, but it doesn't work either ...

Comment: I may try to launch the server in a build then, from this build launch another build that carries all the other steps, but I'm not sure it'll work

Comment: See START /? . You may be able to use "/D path" to eliminate the CD., Also, add some logging to a temp file in your bat file.

Comment: @A.Joly Any update on this issue? Are you using the [**batch script**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/batch-script) task in your build pipeline ? Could you share the detail configuration of the  batch script task?

Comment: Yes, I use this task. in the 'path' I set the path where my script is, in the advanced/working folder I set the path where the batch that launches the server is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, 
Just in case someone else goes through the same kind of issue, I found a workaround:

I wish to mix different command line steps, some of them launching Python scripts:

I have one step for launching the server that is required for my testing tool, one step for my testing tool and one Python step for differential testing

I realized that I could embed everything in a Python script.
It can handle server launching process in a separate window (with subprocess), launch my Python part and launch another process for my validation tool.

I have to test the whole chain but, at least, I solved my problem of launching a background process and detach it from TFS

Answer (score 1):

It's suggest to launch the .bat file from a relative  path not directly use cd to hard code the path.

Also recommend you to use Run Batch File task not **[Run Command Line task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/command-line)** to launch the .bat file.

According to your description, seems you are using a run command line task in your build pipeline. Then  run the command under the working directory `c:\Build_work\5\s`, the command cd to `C:\Users\TFSService\mbs-iot-sdk\osgi\bin\vms\jdk\` on the build agent, find the `server.bat`, run the `server.bat`.

First check if the .bat file is located at the path you are specifying **on the build agent**. Not sure if the bat file have to run under `C:\Users\TFSService\mbs-iot-sdk\osgi\bin\vms\jdk\`, guess you are also hard code the path in your `server.bat` file. Suggest you change all the path to relative path, you could use some built-in variable in TFS.

---

As for your workaround in comment, seems you want to chain builds in TFS. The  official docs literally say "not yet" and have a [uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2165043-provide-build-configuration-dependencies-in-tfs-bu) in planed. However you could use some workaround, such as create or use other's  customize extension (use rest api) to call another build. Detail ways please refer *huserben*'s answer in this question: [How to chain builds in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270617/how-to-chain-builds-in-tfs-2015)

Note sure you have to go deep into this area for your original issue. Just add some related info in case you are interested or need.

Comment: If I use C:\Build_work\5\s as working directory it doesn't change anything (launching ok, but stops at the end of the step). My batch is located at the path specified on the build agent. However, I thought about another way: as for launching a newman command I previousely do npm install of newman, I was wondering if I should not do a step with npm install java as my batch requires it ... unfortunately I encounter further problems then.

Comment: I tried to run the user-agent interactively in order to have the console display in a separate window. It doesn't work either. Though the server managed to launch without blocking twice during my tries. It happened on a server launching related failure, not blocking for launching. I could not figure out why it happened.