# Define TFS build definition dependency and order

Tags: tfs, build, agent

I have 2 build definition with 2 agent in TFS that run separately. builds run using one build one agent. one of builds should start when another build complete, because second build use first build result. second build should run in separate machine because it have specific demands that I don't have in first machine.
I did some searching and found very little about tfs build triggers. I want when first build finished I could trigger second build. its possible???
I am using TFS 2017 Update 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would like to do is chaining builds (one build calls another build definition)。

This is not support by official yet. There had also been a related uservoice and under **planned** status:

> [Provide build configuration dependencies in TFS Build](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2165043-provide-build-configuration-dependencies-in-tfs-bu)
>
> *Provide the ability to create build configuration dependencies such that the success of one build configuration can trigger another build
>   configuration such as a successful build triggering the building of an
>   installation package or a build configuration which deploys to a
>   development or staging server.*

For now, you could use **Rest API** to call another build definition and trigger the build as workaround. There is a [custom build task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin%3Frealm)  written by *Benj Huser* which literally does the work perfectly. For more details have a look at  his answer in this question:  [How to chain builds in TFS 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270617/how-to-chain-builds-in-tfs-2015)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following build task.  It is good for kicking off multiple builds and being able to run them in a certain order.

Just list the builds you want to run in the build definition name field.

[Queue Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jb.queue-build)